# How to access to a shared mail box using Oauth2 with Java (javax.mail)

Tags: java, email, oauth-2.0, outlook, imap

I'm trying to access a ***shared mailbox*** using an ***Oauth2*** and ***IMAP*** Protocol, but I have an error saying that the authentification have failed:

```
Exception in component tJava_1 (Extract_Mails)
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at routines.TalendMail.mailProcess(TalendMail.java:76)
at interfaces.extract_mails_0_1.Extract_Mails.tJava_1Process(Extract_Mails.java:4843)
at interfaces.extract_mails_0_1.Extract_Mails.tLibraryLoad_1Process(Extract_Mails.java:5033)
... 3 more
```

I'm trying to connect with an object Store:

```
final Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(serveur, 993, "user@outlook.com/shared_mail_box", accessToken);
```

And setting an object Propreties:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");

    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

    props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");

    props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");

    props.put("mail.debug", "false");

    props.put("mail.debug.auth", "false");

    System.setProperty("mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter", "true");

    System.setProperty("mail.mime.multipart.allowempty", "true");  
     
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
```

***Note*** : I have successfuly connected to my user mailbox (user@outlook.com) after that I get an access token. But now, I have an issue with trying to connect to my shared mailbox.

Any ideas of how we can access a shared mailbox when it come to an **Oauth2** protocol?

Comment: Your package names should contain your domain name in reverse.

Comment: Package names ? you're refering to what part of code ? the position of the user mail and the shared mail box ? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen